# tomcat maven plugin upgrade to tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, plugins, maven

So I want to start running tomcat 7 locally.
So I grabbed the plugin and its dependency and updated my pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/mapp</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Now when I run `mvn clean install tomcat7:run` it chunks through then spits out the following error:

```
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/mapp
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at c:\dev\bing-branch\mapp\target\tomcat
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement`

SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addFilter
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:848)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1774)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1765)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1171)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/mapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addFilter
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2719)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1054)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1774)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1765)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1171)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addFilter
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:848)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
        ... 26 more
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line 11 column 14
Feb 8, 2012 4:34:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="mapp" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>parish</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I've checked and rechecked the dependencies, including a jar search after the fact on the target directory and the only WebXml classes are coming from the `mapp-0.1/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-catalina-7.0.25.jar` and `./mapp-0.1/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-catalina-7.0.25.jar` jars.  Anyone else know what I could try.  I'm stumped.

Comment: I am surprised to see those JARs in your WEB-INF/lib directory. Are you sure your dependencies are correct?

Comment: I think so, I assume they are in the lib folder due to the tomcat7-maven-plugin plugin.

Comment: So you do not have explicit dependencies towards those JARs, right?

Comment: I do not have any explicit dependencies towards those jars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110660/porting-tomcat-6-to-7-problem-with-filter.  This suggests a workaround/solution.

Comment: Yeah, not a duplicate -- my app is not including that jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the tomcat dependency in the pom.xml adding scope provided and it fixed the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add the plugin as a dependency !!
It's a plugin so just declare it in the pluginManagement or plugins sections.
Have a look at various pom samples available here: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/ .