# How to use catalina.jar

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using websocket function of tomcat 7.0.39, so I have to include catalina.jar into my classpath. But when I deploy my project, if I deploy the jar files into WEB-INF/lib, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
```

and when catalina.jar is not deployed, I get ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound
```

Someone please help me.

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1057)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:604)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1759)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2915)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1694)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Comment: Look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189371/exception-when-running-tomcat-server-org-apache-catalina-deploy-webxml-addservle,http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.in/2011/05/random-tomcat-error.html

Comment: thx, but I don't think it's the same situation

Answer (score 1):

The web socket support in 7.0.x is experiemental (and will soon be deprecated and replaced with a port of the JSR 356 implementation from Tomcat 8).

A side-effect of this is that the API can and does change between point releases. Therefore, you must compile your code againt the Tomcat JARs from the Tomcat version you intend to deploy on. There errors you are seeing are an indication of a version mis-match.

There is no need to package any Tomcat JARs in your web application.

Comment: I was just playing with websockets and wanted to build a simple application with tomcat. I used eclipse to deploy my project, the problem went away when I switched to maven for packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to put the catalina.jar in your classpath. Catalina.jar should already be present in tomcat/lib directory. Tomcat class loader will load the jar from its own lib directory and hence it is the parent class loader so your classpath or application catalina.jar will not picked. Hope you will be able to resolve your problem with this information.

You are getting NoSuchMethodDefinition error, which means the jar which you are using for compiling has that method but the jar, which is loaded for execution does not have that method definition. Check with replacing the catalina.jar in tomcat/lib with the jar that you are using for compiling your code.

Comment: If it is the case, everything should work when the jar file is not deployed, but still I get ClassNotFoundException

Comment: You are getting NoSuchMethodDefinition error, which means the jar which you are using for compiling has that method but the jar, which is loaded for execution does not have that method definition. Check with replacing the catalina.jar in tomcat/lib with the jar that you are using for compiling your code.

Comment: I used exactly the same jars from tomcat/lib, the problem went away when I used maven for packaging and deploying, I guess it might just be a compatibility issue between eclipse and tomcat.