# Unable to deploy my project on tomcat where i have deployed previously on glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I have a project developed on netbeans where i deployed it on glassfish.. But now as i am trying to deploy it on tomcat7. I am facing following exception

```
 INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\OpsConsole\Anil Babu\apache-tomcat-7.
    0.40\webapps\OpsBackEnd.war
    Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
    SEVERE: End event threw exception
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addFilter
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUt
    ils.java:855)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:105
    1)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endEleme
    nt(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
    l.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
    l$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(X
   MLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
    l.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
    ML11Configuration.java:835)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
    ML11Configuration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.
   java:123)
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Ab
   stractSAXParser.java:1210)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
    arse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.j
    ava:1890)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
    a:1259)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
    g.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
    g.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
    eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
    se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
    t.java:5269)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
    .java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
     7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:


      1654)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
        1)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
         java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
         .java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

         Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
         SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/OpsBackEnd/WE
         B-INF/web.xml
         org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/OpsBackEnd/WEB-INF/web.
         xml; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 14; Error at (6, 14) : org.apache.catalina.dep
         loy.WebXml addFilter
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.
     java:2687)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.
     java:2719)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:105
     4)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endEleme
     nt(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
     l.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
    l$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(X
    MLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
     l.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
     ML11Configuration.java:835)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
     ML11Configuration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.
     java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Ab
     stractSAXParser.java:1210)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
     arse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.j
    ava:1890)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
    a:1259)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
g.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5269)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1654)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml ad
dFilter
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUt
ils.java:855)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:105
1)
        ... 30 more

    Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
    SEVERE: Occurred at line 6 column 14
    Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart

    SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
    Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error getConfigured
    Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/OpsBackEnd] startup failed due to previous errors
    Nov 14, 2013 1:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

Please help me out. I am trying to deploy this war on tomcat7 but it was throwing above exception. Can any please help me out to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

there are the jars in my WEB-INF/lib

```
file.reference.appserv-admin.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/appserv-admin.jar
file.reference.appserv-deployment-client.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/more jars to be added for CMDBWS/appserv-deployment-client.jar
file.reference.appserv-ext.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/more jars to be added for CMDBWS/appserv-ext.jar
file.reference.appserv-rt.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/appserv-rt.jar
file.reference.axis-ant.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/axis-ant.jar
file.reference.axis.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/axis.jar
file.reference.client-sdk-resources=../../../../resources for opensso/on VM/client-sdk/resources
file.reference.commons-discovery-0.2.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/commons-discovery-0.2.jar
file.reference.commons-lang.jar=../../JARS/commons-lang.jar
file.reference.commons-logging-1.0.4.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
file.reference.ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar
file.reference.ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar-1=web\\WEB-INF\\lib\\ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar
file.reference.imqjmsra.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/imqjmsra.jar
file.reference.jaxrpc.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/jaxrpc.jar
file.reference.jgraphx.jar=../../JARS/jgraphx.jar
file.reference.log4j-1.2.15.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/log4j-1.2.15.jar
file.reference.log4j-1.2.8.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/log4j-1.2.8.jar
file.reference.log4j-1.2.8.jar-1=../../JARS/log4j-1.2.8.jar
file.reference.on_VM-client-sdk=../../../../resources for opensso/on VM/client-sdk
file.reference.postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar=C:\\OpsConsole\\postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar
file.reference.SudhaWork-org=../../org
file.reference.wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar=../../JARS/JARS for CMDB WS/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
includes=**
j2ee.compile.on.save=false
j2ee.copy.static.files.on.save=false
j2ee.deploy.on.save=false
j2ee.platform=1.5
j2ee.platform.classpath=${j2ee.server.middleware}/mq/lib/jaxm-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/javax.annotation-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/bean-validator.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.batch-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.ejb-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.el.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.faces.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.inject.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.interceptor-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.jms-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.json.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.mail.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.management.j2ee-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.persistence.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.resource-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.security.jacc-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.transaction-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.websocket-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.ws.rs-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.xml.registry-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar
j2ee.platform.embeddableejb.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar
j2ee.platform.wscompile.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsgen.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsimport.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsit.classpath=
j2ee.server.type=gfv3ee6
jar.compress=false
javac.classpath=\
    ${file.reference.ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar-1}:\
    ${file.reference.axis-ant.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.appserv-deployment-client.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.appserv-ext.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.appserv-rt.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.axis.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.commons-discovery-0.2.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.commons-logging-1.0.4.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.imqjmsra.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jaxrpc.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.log4j-1.2.8.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.commons-lang.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jgraphx.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.appserv-admin.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar}
```

the above is a part of my project.properties... please let me know, if any of the above jars are not valid

Comment: is your application using jndi datasource ?

Comment: is `catalina.jar` file included in the `.war` file?

Comment: yes @Ashish. it is using jndi datasource

Comment: No.. do i need to include?. It is there in the tomcat lib. so i didn't include

Comment: No you don't need to include it. [You can take a look on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189371/exception-when-running-tomcat-server-org-apache-catalina-deploy-webxml-addservle) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110660/porting-tomcat-6-to-7-problem-with-filter)

Comment: They didn't help me out..

Comment: Check this [http://blog.xeiam.com/blog/2013/01/05/a-random-tomcat-error/](http://blog.xeiam.com/blog/2013/01/05/a-random-tomcat-error/) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189371/exception-when-running-tomcat-server-org-apache-catalina-deploy-webxml-addservle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189371/exception-when-running-tomcat-server-org-apache-catalina-deploy-webxml-addservle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete

```
 appserv-admin.jar, servlet-api.jar and appserv-deployment-client.jar
```

from web-inf/lib folder of your war..

It deploys well on tomcat..

Answer (score -1):

1) keep your .war file inside the webapps folder

2) go into bin directory and start the tomcat server `./startup.sh` by this command

if you want to configure datasource [jndi resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

or to get started soon with datasource you can put your datasource information inside context.xml of your tomcat server. which is like

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="datasource" password="root" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tmpDb" username="root"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes... i have created jndi resource, still i am getting above exception

Comment: you might be using catalina.jar or catalina dependencies in your project(jar or as dependency in your maven), just remove it.

Comment: I ave tried placing catalina.jar in web-inf/lib.. still problem persists @Ashish. ... Where will be the dependecy to remove?.. Kindly let me know possible dependecies...

Comment: you dont have to include catalina.jar, try without it.

Comment: I have tried without catalina from beginning.. no use.. same problem persists.. shall i give list of the jars in web-inf/lib ... ?. @Ashish.....................

Comment: @Ashish.. I have added jars in the question. can you please check and give me solution